# Infrequently used GitHub self-hosted runners

Tags: github-actions

We do not do a lot of development and are looking to replace our current setup of Bamboo and SVN with GitHub and GitHub Actions with self-hosted runners (we need to deploy code behind a firewall). [The documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/removing-self-hosted-runners) says:

> A self-hosted runner is automatically removed from GitHub if it has not connected to GitHub Actions for more than 14 days.

We typically do not deploy code every 14 days. Is there a way around having to set up runners every time we want to deploy something to our intranet?

Comment: Why not trigger one job per day or week that simply runs your test pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently read this as well.

This is not an issue because the runners phone-home periodically whether you are running jobs or not, so the machine the runner is on just has to be able to reach GitHub in order to satisfy the "connected to GitHub" requirement.

In fact, this is a key component of how the runners work, they are constantly "phoning home" or long-polling so that when a new job is queued in GitHub Actions, the runner will pick it up within a certain polling interval.

This is explained in the GitHub Docs: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/about-self-hosted-runners#communication-between-self-hosted-runners-and-github

Comment: Hi,  can you find any documentation that supports that idea?

Comment: @gabriel I updated the post with a link to the documentation